# writing a "Compare - Equals" function in HLSL / CG i.e. isequals(a,b)

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, equals, hlsl

I want to have isequals(a,b) comparisons using graphics arithemtic on 2 integers, (i can't use logical If operator as i need linear logic), to:

return 1 if a=b
return 0 if a!=b

For example, i can write:

```
  1-saturate(distance(a,b));  // to return 1 if a = b.
```

and

```
  1-step(abs(a-b));
```

is there a faster way to do it in cg maths?

Comment: Can you please explain why you can't simply test for `a == b`? Please hurry, my head is about to explode.

Comment: because i am making a selector for 640 possible combinations of maths functions, ... using if(a==b) in shader model 3 it will unroll-compile the 640 combinations into about 64000 maths instructions. if construct a linear if selector that devides all other possibilities by zero, it perhaps is more effictient on sm3. and i have to wait a week to have a dx11 graphics card.

Comment: i.e. 10 x 10 x 10 selections using if is 1000 combinations, and using multiply by zero is 1 long maths function where 27 out of 30 parts of teh function is unselected and devided by zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float result = (a == b); // Works in HLSL...
```

What makes you think == isn't what you want?

Comment: Thanks that sounds great! i ll be trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

What about sat(abs(a-b)*FLOAT_MAX) ?
abs and sat should both be free on arithmetic. 
This might break in implementation dependent ways if a and b are very close.
If you need to invert you can always do sat(1-x).

Comment: Thanks that's great also! i wish i could understand computational cost of the different instructions in hlsl, it's just similar ratio to x86 except faster?